# Azure Face Recognition gives "Attribute 'qualityForRecognition' is only supported for recognition_03 and recognition_04." error

Tags: azure, rest, azure-cognitive-search, facial-identification

I'm following the official MS Azure quickstart guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/client-libraries?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-rest-api), specifically the "Get face attributes" part and when replicating provided cURL examples in Postman, I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "Attribute 'qualityForRecognition' is only supported for recognition_03 and recognition_04."
    }
}
```

Any ideas? It seems like they've updated their API without updating documentation, which is something I wouldn've expected from a corp like Microsoft, but it's the only thing I can think of why it wouldn't be working. For reference, here's a screenshot of my Postman request.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/faceapi/face/detect-with-stream#uri-parameters):

> To extract face attributes, call the Detect API again, but set detectionModel to detection_01. Add the `returnFaceAttributes` query parameter as well.

**Detect with stream example:**

```
POST {Endpoint}/face/v1.0/detect?overload=stream&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise&recognitionModel=recognition_01&returnRecognitionModel=True&detectionModel=detection_01
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {API key}
```

- `returnFaceAttributes`: Analyze and return the one or more specified face attributes in the comma-separated string like "returnFaceAttributes=age,gender".

**Note:** `detection_01` supports age, gender, headPose, smile, facialHair, glasses, emotion, hair, makeup, occlusion, accessories, blur, exposure, noise, and qualityForRecognition While `detection_02` does not support any attributes and `detection_03` only supports mask and `qualityForRecognition`. `qualityForRecognition` is only supported when the 'recognitionModel' is specified as '**recognition_03**' or '**recognition_04**'.

As per [Add QualityForRecognition in Face how-to samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/pull/296/files/b6229e48a8cac4fd16c244416516892163080200), `detection_01` is used with `recognition_04`

```
var faces3 = await faceClient.Face.DetectWithUrlAsync(url: imageUrl, returnFaceId: true, returnFaceAttributes: requiredFaceAttributes, detectionModel: DetectionModel.Detection01, recognitionModel: RecognitionModel.Recognition04);
```

You can also refer to [Add qualityForRecognition attribute to Face Detection](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/pull/16449)

Comment: Hi @DeepDave-MT, for some reason just switching `detection_03` to `detection_01` didn't help, but that link to list of parameters pointed me to the right direction and once I added the `recognitionModel=recognition_04`, it has started working. In the docs it says `recognition_01` is the default, so that's probably why. It might be worth mentioning that in the quickstart guide.